# How does soap actually reduce surface tension of water

Tags: surface-chemistry, surfactants

I was a bit confused on how soap reduce surface tension of water.I've read some answers like [Why does soap reduce surface tension of water](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/35840/why-does-soap-reduce-surface-tension-of-water) and [Why do surfactants lower the surface tension](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/111350/why-do-surfactants-lower-the-surface-tension)
But the answers given don't clears my doubt that **if the soap molecules come to the surface to separate the water molecules and weaken the hydrogen bond, wouldn't they form stronger ion dipole interactions and increase the surface tension**.I mean they would attract the water molecules with greater force.
I do understand from the energy point of view but I wanted to understand it considering the forces.

I know that it is a repeated question but consider giving an explanation to my point.